# How to programmatically add view in Constraint layout?

Tags: android, view, kotlin, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to design the below layout

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/before_breakfast_option"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/diabetes_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:text="water"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/toogle_diabeties"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>

            <TextView
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:text="almonds"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:id="@+id/toogle_diabeties"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

using the below code:

```
 var textView= TextView(this@DietStepFive)
                    textView.id=100
                    textView.text="water"
                    textView.background=ContextCompat.getDrawable(this@DietStepFive,R.drawable.rectangle_diet)
                    textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this@DietStepFive,R.color.black))

                    var textView1= TextView(this@DietStepFive)
                    textView1.id=101
                    textView1.text="almonds"
                    textView1.background=ContextCompat.getDrawable(this@DietStepFive,R.drawable.rectangle_diet)
                    textView1.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this@DietStepFive,R.color.black))

                    var constraintset= ConstraintSet()
                    constraintset.clone(before_breakfast_option)

                    //left to left of
                    constraintset.connect(textView.id,ConstraintSet.LEFT,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.LEFT,0)
                    //baseline
                    constraintset.connect(textView.id,ConstraintSet.BASELINE,textView1.id,ConstraintSet.BASELINE,0)
                    //right to right of
                    constraintset.connect(textView1.id,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,0)
                    //top to top of
                    constraintset.connect(textView1.id,ConstraintSet.TOP,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.TOP,0)

                    constraintset.applyTo(before_breakfast_option)

                    before_breakfast_option.addView(textView)
                    before_breakfast_option.addView(textView1)
```

But the XML code is giving me the layout which has two textview one is one left side and one is one right side but kotlin code is giving me the both the textview overlapping on left side. Why?

what wents wrong? any lead?

Comment: Add layout gravity to both the TextView

Comment: I have added the Left gravity to textview and Right to textview1 but nothing happens @TerrilThomas

Comment: layout_gravity rather than just gravity

Comment: I can't add the layout_gravity property since for this I need to wrap the textview in linear layout with width match_parent but I don't want to do like that. @TerrilThomas

Comment: Moreover, It solves the question but generally, I want to add as many views in the layout till there is no space left. For that problem, I can't set the gravity. @TerrilThomas

Comment: @TerrilThomas XML is working fine without adding the gravity, then why not it is working through my kotlin code.

Answer (score 3):

Add the `TextView`s to the layout then connect them just like you did when setting up the XML. You added the views THEN connected them.

Move

```
before_breakfast_option.addView(textView)
before_breakfast_option.addView(textView1)
```

before

```
var constraintset= ConstraintSet()
```

and everything should work.

Comment: It is not working as expected. Result is same as before @Cheticamp

Comment: @AnkurKhandelwal You definitely need to do the move, but that may not be your only issue. I am not familiar with Kotlin so, if it is a Kotlin issue, I can't help. I am wondering what `before_breakfast_option` refers to and are you actually getting your constraints applied. Here is a [quick gist](https://gist.github.com/Cheticamp/4e74a6210728b952cb35e7e2a5656b91) of working code in Java that you can take a look at. It may help you figure out your remaining issues.

Comment: @AnkurKhandelwal I did a conversion of the above-mentioned gist to Kotlin and ran the result with success. Here is the [Kotlin version](https://gist.github.com/Cheticamp/e0af76d73f7a10367efe4dde4ff2f877) of the working Java code. I hope this helps.

Comment: I didn't get time to check your code ( thanks for making gist and so kind of you)  but  I got the solution. Actually, I was using the wrong constraint and yes addview will call before setting the constraint. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe anyone else will use it in future. A sound sleep and work done. 
I was using the wrong constraint.

Instead of this

```
//left to left of
constraintset.connect(textView.id,ConstraintSet.LEFT,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.LEFT,0)
//baseline
constraintset.connect(textView.id,ConstraintSet.BASELINE,textView1.id,ConstraintSet.BASELINE,0)
//right to right of
constraintset.connect(textView1.id,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,0)
//top to top of
constraintset.connect(textView1.id,ConstraintSet.TOP,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.TOP,0)
```

use this

```
//left to right of
constraintset.connect(textView1.id,ConstraintSet.LEFT,textView.id,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,10)
//baseline
constraintset.connect(textView1.id,ConstraintSet.BASELINE,textView.id,ConstraintSet.BASELINE,0)
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to replace   `app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"`

with
`app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/toogle_diabeties"`